# Question just like this one was marked duplicate, but I disagree; what action to take?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, duplicates

Suppose we have the following three questions:

- Question 1: [Can I include the completion of Udacity and Coursera classes I have attended in an academic CV?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/2336/can-i-include-the-completion-of-udacity-and-coursera-classes-i-have-attended-in)
- Question 2: [Is an X-Series Certificate from edx useful for graduate school?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/25951/is-an-x-series-certificate-from-edx-useful-for-graduate-school)
- Question 3: [How would a Coursera specialization be regarded in graduate admissions?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/28405/how-would-a-coursera-specialization-be-regarded-in-graduate-admissions)

Question 2 was long ago marked as a duplicate of Question 1. However, I do not think it is an exact duplicate.

Question 3 was just asked, and I think it is an exact duplicate of Question 2.

What to do now?

I don't want to vote it as a duplicate of Question 1, since I don't think it is.

I also don't want to vote it as a duplicate of Question 2, since Question 2 is itself a duplicate.

And I don't want to leave it open, since I think it's an exact duplicate of an existing question.

I suggested that the OP edit it to highlight the difference from Question 2, but I still think it's fundamentally the same question.

Comment: Why not reopening Q2 in the first place?

Comment: @Piotr just saw this comment, sorry. As a mod, I can't cast a vote to reopen like a "normal" user, and this isn't straightforward enough to warrant using a magic moderator reopen.

Comment: This exact question is addressed here on Meta.SE: [Someone flagged my question as already answered, but it's not](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194476/someone-flagged-my-question-as-already-answered-but-its-not)

Answer (score 1):

My pragmatic proposal would be to just leave it open. While it may be a duplicate of Question 2, Question 2 is closed and hence "does not really exist". It should be closed if it is a duplicate of Question 1, but as you say it isn't, I see no reason to mark it as duplicate.

More generally, I think it is important to consider closing as duplicate as *"these are very similar questions, to the extend that the answers will be pretty much the same"*, and not *"these are absolutely identical questions"*. With the first, more practical, definition in mind, it becomes clear that being a duplicate is not necessarily a transitive relationship (that is, it is possible that A is a duplicate of B, B of C, but A not of C).

Comment: I think you mean transitive, rater than transient.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Yup, thanks.

Comment: (1) I don't think that making paths any longer than one in the dupe graph makes any sense. (2) ad "more practical definition": A question should be only a duplicate if it's clear that the answers apply for the question being closed, this may require some comments being kept in the closed question explaining how exactly it is a duplicate.

Answer (score -2):

I don't think the fact that question 2 is itself a duplicate of something is a reason not to close question 3 as a duplicate of it. If you do close Q3 as a duplicate of Q2, it keeps the "duplication graph" sensible in case question 2 is reopened sometime in the future. And if that doesn't happen, someone browsing the questions is still going to be pointed to Q1 in the end. The only thing you give up by closing Q3 as a duplicate of Q2 rather than of Q1 is a slight amount of convenience on the part of the reader.

So I would recommend closing question 3 as a duplicate of question 2.